# Frequent "offset out of range" messages, partitions deserted by consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

We are running 3 node Kafka 0.10.0.1 cluster. We have a consumer application which has a single consumer group connecting to multiple topics. We are seeing strange behaviour in consumer logs. With these lines

```
 Fetch offset 1109143 is out of range for partition email-4, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 952168 is out of range for partition email-7, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 945796 is out of range for partition email-5, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 950900 is out of range for partition email-0, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 953163 is out of range for partition email-3, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 1118389 is out of range for partition email-6, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 1112177 is out of range for partition email-2, resetting offset
 Fetch offset 1109539 is out of range for partition email-1, resetting offset
```

Some time later we saw these logs

```
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: ConsumerCoordinator:333 - Revoking previously assigned partitions [sms-4, sms-3, sms-0, sms-2, sms-1] for group notifications-consumer
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator:381 - (Re-)joining group notifications-consumer
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: AbstractCoordinator$1:349 - Successfully joined group notifications-consumer with generation 3063
[2018-06-08 19:45:28] :: INFO  :: ConsumerCoordinator:225 - Setting newly assigned partitions [sms-8, sms-7, sms-9, sms-6, sms-5] for group notifications-consumer
```

I noticed that one of our topics was not seen in the list of Setting newly assigned partitions. Then that topic had no consumers attached to it for 8 hours at least. It's only when someone restarted application it started consuming from that topic. What can be going wrong here?

Here is consumer config

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 3000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [x.x.x.x:9092, x.x.x.x:9092, x.x.x.x:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.id =
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = otp-notifications-consumer
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = null
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 50
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 305000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = SSL
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 300000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = /x/x/client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

The topic which went orphan has 10 partitions, retention.ms=1800000, segment.ms=1800000.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

The offset out of range message you are seeing usually indicates the offset the consumer is at has been deleted on the broker. Upon hitting that the consumer will use `auto.offset.reset` to restart consuming.

With `retention.ms=1800000` (30mins), you are only keeping data for a very short amount of time so it's expected that if you restart the consumer after several hours, the data is gone.

Comment: Only the thing here is that my consumer process never stops, its a daemon. So how come randomly from in-between it stops, gets detached and never comes back up only for a certain topic?