# Keep getting Fetch offset is out of range for partition resetting offset

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka

We have a spring boot application that reads from topic XXXX and writes to topic YYYY
We have noticed that Topic YYYY contains duplicate records
After some investigation we saw the following **WARN** message in spring boot application's log

```
Fetch offset 948982335 is out of range for partition XXXX-6, resetting offset
Resetting offset for partition XXXX-6 to offset 568675320.
```

we are suspecting that this warning message is what causes the duplication.

so:

After some research we found the following answers [frequent-offset-out-of-range-messages-partitions-deserted-by-consumer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894710/frequent-offset-out-of-range-messages-partitions-deserted-by-consumer) and [kafka-consumer-offsets-out-of-range-with-no-configured-reset-policy-for-partitio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320643/kafka-consumer-offsets-out-of-range-with-no-configured-reset-policy-for-partitio) , but it did not explain neither the cause nor the solution.

and this is a code snippet for my spring application

```
topology.addSource("XXXXRawSourceInput", configProperties.XXXX)
            .addProcessor("XXXXProcessor", ProcessorSupplier {
                XXXXProcessor()
            }, "XXXXSourceInput")
            .addSink("SinkRawProcessorToYYYY", "YYYY", "XXXXProcessor")
```

This is my server config

```yaml
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
#broker.id=0
broker.id.generation.enable=true

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://km-kafka06:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=30

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
#num.io.threads=8
num.io.threads=16

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
#log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
log.dirs=/data/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
#num.partitions=1
num.partitions=7

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
#num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=4

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended to ensure availability such as 3.
#offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
#transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
#transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=3

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=480

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=km-zookeeper01:2181,km-zookeeper02:2181,km-zookeeper03:2181 

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
#group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=5000

# To enable topics deletion
delete.topic.enable=false

# To enable topic auto creation
```

1- **Why this behavior keeps happening**?
2- **How to solve this issue**?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was a bug in kafka, solved after upgrading,

same issue mentioned here: [Consumer offset reset after new segment rolling](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-9543)

Comment: What version was affected by the bug? What version did the bug fix land in? Is there a ticket/issue where we can see the bug discussed?

Comment: @AlexKahn I edited the answer, link is added now.